# safeTransferFrom of ERC721 not working when transfering NFT to a safe address

Tags: contract-invocation, nft, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I was trying to transfer an NFT using ERC721's `safeTransferFrom` method from my gnosis safe to another gnosis safe address but while executing the transaction I am getting -

```js
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":3,"message":"execution reverted: GS013","data":"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054753303133000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x3c7c3487d6782266059193C2593D6a2f9aC43989","to":"0x01d0a2c2fE8d8B08B3Df890cA5dBE4aBCE1Fa642","data":"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","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.5.3)
{
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  error: {
    code: 3,
    message: 'execution reverted: GS013',
    data: '0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054753303133000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
  },
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0x3c7c3487d6782266059193C2593D6a2f9aC43989',
    to: '0x01d0a2c2fE8d8B08B3Df890cA5dBE4aBCE1Fa642',
    data: '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',
    accessList: null
  }
}
```

On executing the same transaction with a different target address, i.e, my Metamask wallet address(EOA) it is working fine. Also when I tried transferring the NFT from my Metamask wallet to gnosis safe address via Opensea UI(Profile -> NFT -> Transfer) then also it is not working but working when the target address is my Metamask wallet address. So, I further checked and found Opensea UI also uses `safeTransferFrom` method to transfer NFTs.

Now, another thing I found is that transferring NFT to a safe address works fine with `transferFrom` method of ERC721.

So, not sure but I think the reason could be, as mentioned [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721-safeTransferFrom-address-address-uint256-):

> If the target address is a contract, it must implement
> IERC721Receiver.onERC721Received, which is called upon a safe
> transfer, and return the magic value
> bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"));
> otherwise, the transfer is reverted.

This is the [decoded data](https://rimeissner.dev/transaction-decoder/#/?data=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) of the transaction which was failing.

- Why `safeTransferFrom` is not working when target address is gnosis safe?
- Is it fine to use `transferFrom` method as `safeTransferFrom` is not working?

***Edit:***
It is a bug in the gnosis SDK and an issue exist [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/issues/183) for this. Once gnosis team fix this, I will mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fallback handler that allows to handle NFTs is missing in the recipient Safe.

Fixed here how to add a fallback handler to a given Safe and adding a default fallback handler to newly deployed Safes: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/issues/262

Answer (score 1):

I will refer to OpenZeppelin's [ERC721](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721) implementation throughout my answer.

> Why `safeTransferFrom` is not working when target address is gnosis safe?

Because the Gnosis Safe contract does not implement the [`IERC721Receiver`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Receiver) interface, which must be implemented by smart contract that receive NFTs if you want to use the [`safeTransferFrom`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-safeTransferFrom) function.

To quote the [original spec](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) of ERC721, "a wallet/broker/auction application MUST implement the wallet interface if it will accept safe transfers."

> Is it fine to use `transferFrom` method as `safeTransferFrom` is not working?

Yes, because Gnosis Safe is a multi-signature wallet that can execute any function from any third-party smart contract.

The rationale in the original spec of ERC721 was to prevent accidental transfers to contracts that can no longer transfer the NFT.

That is not a risk with Gnosis Safe. If you get enough signatures, you can choose to transfer the NFT by calling the NFT contract.

Comment: Thank you for this Paul.  Just to clarify, is there anything about safeMint or any form of "safe" transfer that prevents somebody from accidentally sending to an unused account (say due to a typo in the address entered in a text box) so long as that address is -not- an address of a published smart  contract which fails to implement the IERC721Receiver?  I presume not, but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: The answer is "no" - the ERC-721 defines "safety" in terms of whether the recipient smart contracts implements `IERC721Receiver`. Any other edge cases (such as unused accounts, or incorrect recipients) are up to the app/ contract developer to handle.